# Can I be possible create multiple company without install multiple SurgarCRM opensource?

Tags: php, crm, sugarcrm

As I know, the SugarCRM is installed for one company. So Are there any ways to create multiple company without install multiple SurgarCRM?.

I have 5 companies belong to different fields (Education, IT service, Law...) and I don't wanna install 5 SugarCRM packages in my server and it's really inconvenience for management if I do that.

By the way, I have used newest SugarCRM's version so far.

Please help me and thank you guys so much!

Comment: Off-topic - You're asking about not having to pay relevant license fees per install

Comment: Not necessarily. It's a legit question as many want to host the free edition (no license fees to avoid) in such a fashion to make it easier to manage the instance. I've seen this for companies with many child companies along with vertical hosting providers.

Comment: Hi @egg, so I have research in many time about this issue, they advise me like what you told me above. So thanks so much.